# make relation transitive

Tags: set, relation, discrete-mathematics

A= set of actors
M: A → a
M={(x,y)|x and y appear in the same movie}

M is reflexive
M is symetric
M is NOT transitive

What my problem is to turn M relation to equvalance relation namely transitive relation.

Comment: Cannot be done. Only way would be to shoot one or more movies with the appropriate actors. However, a lot of them are already dead. Or do you just need an algorithm to compute the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of M?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wanted to compute the transitive closure of a binary relation [Transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure). The standard solutions should be the [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).